# "Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression" при обработке ответа от сервера

Tags: javascript, jquery

Всем привет. Имеется строка `&#x440;&#x443;&#x431;.260000`, которая содержится в  `value`. Символы `&#x440;` это кириллические буквы. Выполняю условие:

```
// Ajax action
$.post( wc_add_to_cart_params.ajax_url, data, function( response ) {
    fragments = response.fragments;
    if ( fragments ) {
    $.each(fragments, function(key, value) {
        $(key).replaceWith( $( $.trim( value ) ));
    });
}
}
```

В консоли получаю ошибку
`Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: &#x440;&#x443;&#x431;.150000`
 и скрипт стопорится. Что делать?

Comment: А `fragments` в вашем коде это что такое?

Comment: @Dmitriy Simushev добавил вверху. А это имеет принципиальное значение?, ведь известно, что jquery ругается именно на `value`

Comment: У меня ощущение, что я только что jQuery увидел впервые. `$(key).replaceWith()` в данном контексте вообще понять не могу. `key` - это число. Мне кажется ничего осмысленного из `$(key)` не получится. Также, скорее всего, ваш скрипт падает на попытке понять `$( $.trim( value ) )`

Comment: Если не сложно, поясните чего вы хотите в результате получить? Вроде все просто, но явно неправильно и не могу понять что именно должно получиться

Comment: @tutankhamun нет, поверьте, осмысленное в нем содержится (each отрабатывает ровно 2 раза, а уже на 3ий валится с этой ошибкой) - я не хочу тут городить многоэтажный код и вывод, чтобы это вам показать, т.к. это еще больше запутает и ошибка заключена в этом фрагменте.

Comment: Какова структура `fragments`?

Comment: @Dmitriy Simushev посмотрите внимательно - я же добавил вверху код

Comment: @tutankhamun можете посмотреть здесь исходник
https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/master/assets/js/frontend/add-to-cart.js

Comment: Тот код, который вы добавили только показывает, что `fragments` -- это одно из полей JSON ответа на POST запрос. А что именно отдает (или должен отдавать) сервер в этом из этого кода не ясно. Поэтому повторю вопрос: какова структура `fragments`?

Comment: На всякий случай: вы же понимаете, что конструкция `$(key)` считает, что `key` это валидный CSS селектор и производит поиск по нему в DOM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ваша проблема в том, что либо ключи либо значения (либо и то и другое) объекта `fragments` не являются валидными CSS селекторами.

Например, вы пытаетесь выбрать элемент соответствующий селектору `&#x440;&#x443;&#x431;.150000` (о чем и ругается jQuery).

Чтобы решить проблему, убедитесь что и значения и ключи возвращаемого с сервера объекта `fragments` -- это валидные селекторы.

**UPD:**

Есть у меня такое чувство, что вы не до конца понимаете, как работает функция `$`. Если я прав (и правильно угадал основную идею этого куска кода), то код ниже должен решить проблему:

```
// Ajax action
$.post(wc_add_to_cart_params.ajax_url, data, function(response) {
    fragments = response.fragments;
    if (fragments) {
        $.each(fragments, function(key, value) {
            $(key).replaceWith( $.trim(value) );
        });
    }
});
```

Обратите внимание на отсутствие оборачивающего `$()` вокруг `$.trim(value)`

Comment: да, @Dmitriy Simushev спасибо - это была ошибка разработчиков плагина)